# Who is Data's creator?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-data

I am kind of new to *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, and when I discovered Data and wondered: who is his creator? I haven't watched all the episodes and would like to know who created Data. Just a bonus, what is Data made of/or what is his programming?

Comment: Data was created by Dr. Noonien Soong (also played by Brent Spiner, suggesting Soong created Data in his own image. Data is also referred to as a "positronic" robot, as a nod to the robot stories of Isaac Asimov. More detail than you could possibly want about everything Star Trek can be found at memory-alpha.org.

Comment: I suggest watching the fourth season episode [Brothers](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Brothers_(episode))

Comment: That is a Next Generation episode, not Enterprise.

Comment: @Xantec A common misconception of people new to the Star Trek as whole, is that they think the TNG is also named by a ship/station, namely Enterprise - like say Voyager, Deep Space 9 (space station) and the new Enterprise. They think that TOS was called Star Trek. It's been like this with some of non-geek people that I talked to about Star Trek.

Comment: @Secko - TOS was called Star Trek... it only became TOS after TNG

Comment: Upvoted, because I don't understand the downvotes. He stated he is fairly new to the series, so why should he know it? By visiting memory-alpha.org he also will be exposed to MANY spoilers, not only the answer to his question. And even if - how could he know memory-alpha.org is THE source for Star Trek, when he obviously is a newbie.

Comment: I went on the website and it DID have a lot of spoilers all right.

Comment: @HorusKol Yes, you are right of course. What I meant to say is that they think that only TOS is called Star Trek, the rest are called by ship/station.

Comment: @Trollwut - Probably downvoted because it shows very little attempt at research. Most SE sites expect at least an attempt at finding information on your own before asking on a site, as referenced in the help section: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JohnP: Yes, I admit this and this is a good argument. But I also mention, that if someone is THAT new, how could he know that memory-alpha is THE confident source and not one with lapses or inconsistency? --- Just again: I know the downvote has its eligibility, I just wouldn't be that rough.

Comment: @Trollwut - It doesn't matter if he knows the memory alpha site or not. Basic research of any search engine and "Who created data" gives the answer. It shows that he did no research at all.

Comment: So I should read all books of JRR Tolkien when I have a related question? :P No, you're right. As I said, the downvote had its eligibility. :)

Comment: I know about the website because i clicked the link on the answer below and read more than i wanted to know.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the answer is super easily accessible or not. It's a valid question. I mean, just look at this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/948135/555690. It's obvious, and it's valid.

Comment: @ATS: If someone doesn't google something up, I would not be surprised at all if they didn't read a SE tag description. It's less likely, I'd say. Besides, it's common to miss branching tags such as [tag:star-trek-data] as the OP did. Frankly, I too would not even think about that specific tag and would be settled with just [tag:star-trek]. It's the same with other questions - not all the Harry Potter questions about Voldemort have the [tag:voldemort] tag.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Memory Alpha (Star Trek Wiki site) is your best resource for all things Star Trek.

[MA's Data article](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Data) tells you what you need:

> Data was the fifth of six known androids designed by [Dr. Noonian Soong](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Noonian_Soong). He was built on the planet Omicron Theta around 2336, after Lore was deactivated, and over the protests of Soong's wife Juliana. Soong claimed he built Data to perfect his design of his androids, and when Data was perfected, apply his improvements to Lore.

Bonus answers (but you should never post >1 question per post on SE, so I will only answer one):

> He was composed of 24.6 kilograms of tripolymer composites, 11.8 kilograms of molybdenum-cobalt alloys and 1.3 kilograms of bioplast sheeting. (TNG: "The Most Toys") ... All told, he weighed approximately one hundred kilograms. (TNG: "Inheritance") Data's upper spinal support was a polyalloy designed to withstand extreme stress. His skull was composed of cortenide and duranium. (TNG: "The Chase")

Further details on Data and similar androids are on http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Soong-type_android

Comment: More on number of androids: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121/how-many-different-soong-robots-were-there

Comment: Data's origins and creator are covered pretty well by the series. There are several episodes dedicated to Data and his "family," so watching the series will also be a good source of info.

In other news, Dr. Noonian Soong is not to be confused with Khan Noonien Singh, who is of no relation.

Answer (score 4):

## Technically speaking, there were two creators

In *TNG* 'Datalore', we learn from Lore and some pretty strong evidence down on Omicron Theta that Data was created by Dr Noonien Soong.  And in *TNG* 'Inheritance', we learn there was another:

> JULIANA: Oh, Data, I was there, right at the beginning on Omicron Theta. **I helped create you.** Now look at you.

([Source](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/262.htm))

So, technically speaking, Data was created by two people: Dr Noonien Soong *and* Dr Juliana Tainer (then Soong).

Comment: Good find!!!!!!!

Comment: @DVK-in-exile Why thank you!